# Trying to create an array from two values of an array

Tags: php, arrays

So I'm iterating over this $elements array. I am trying to get the key and value from each individual item of the $elements array, which is also an array (which I will call $element).

Here's my code:

```
  $options = array();  
  foreach ($elements as $element) {
    if ($element['#active']) {
      continue;
    }


    $options[$element]['#query'] = $element['#indexed_value'];



  }
```

This doesn't work. How would I get the value of $element['#query'] and $element['indexed_value'] as a key => value pair?

Comment: `$options[$element['#query']]=...`

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the array that you're iterating through, and a sample of the expected results?

Comment: At first glance, you are using `$element` as an *array* and as an *array key*. It does not matter what your script is doing; it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 $options[$element['#query']] = $element['#indexed_value'];
```

I execute following code

```
 $options["junaid"] = "hassan";
 echo print_r($options, true);
```

Got following result

```
 Array
 (
     [junaid] => hassan
 )
```

Comment: It gives me, "array()" when I print_r($options, true);

Comment: did you echo $element['#query'] and $element['#indexed_value'] ? what values they have ?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm If I understand the problem:

```
$elements = array(array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' =>3), array('d' =>4, 'e' =>5,'f' =>6) );
$options = array();
$temp = array();
$temp2 = array();

//value is each array in $elements
foreach ($elements as $element) {       
    $temp = array_merge($temp, array_keys($element));   
    $temp2 = array_merge($temp2, array_values($element));   
}
$options = array_combine($temp, $temp2);
var_dump($options);
```

and it produces this output:

```
array(6) { ["a"]=> int(1) ["b"]=> int(2) ["c"]=> int(3) ["d"]=> int(4) ["e"]=> int(5) ["f"]=> int(6) }
```

I used this [website](http://phpfiddle.org/)